# How can I combine the artifacts from multiple Configurations?

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a buildSrc plugin needs to share two types of files (resource files and classpath files) between subprojects.

```kotlin
// buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/my-plugin.gradle.kts

val MyPluginComponent = Attribute.of("my-plugin-component", String::class.java)

dependencies.attributesSchema.attribute(MyPluginComponent)

val myPlugin by configurations.registering {
  description = "Declare dependencies on my-plugin files"
  declarable()
}

val myPluginClasspathResolver by configurations.registering {
  description = "Resolves my-plugin classpath files from declared dependencies"
  resolvable()
  extendsFrom(myPlugin.get())
  attributes {
    attribute(Usage.USAGE_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named("my-plugin"))
    attribute(MyPluginComponent, "classpath")
  }
}

val myPluginClasspathConsumable by configurations.registering {
  description = "Provides my-plugin classpath files"
  consumable()
  attributes {
    attribute(Usage.USAGE_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named("my-plugin"))
    attribute(MyPluginComponent, "classpath")
  }
}

val myPluginResourcesResolver by configurations.registering {
  description = "Resolves my-plugin resource files from declared dependencies"
  resolvable()
  extendsFrom(myPlugin.get())
  attributes {
    attribute(Usage.USAGE_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named("my-plugin"))
    attribute(MyPluginComponent, "resources")
  }
}

val myPluginResourcesConsumable by configurations.registering {
  description = "Provides my-plugin resource files"
  consumable()
  attributes {
    attribute(Usage.USAGE_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named("my-plugin"))
    attribute(MyPluginComponent, "resources")
  }
}

fun Configuration.resolvable() { isCanBeResolved = true;  isCanBeConsumed = false; isCanBeDeclared = false; }
fun Configuration.consumable() { isCanBeResolved = false; isCanBeConsumed = true;  isCanBeDeclared = false; }
fun Configuration.declarable() { isCanBeResolved = false; isCanBeConsumed = false; isCanBeDeclared = true;  }
```

The resource and classpath files need to be recombined in the aggregating project, but they need to be recombined from the source project. So if `lib-alpha` provides resource:`1.txt` and classpath:`dependency1.jar`, then they should be within the same `AggregatedPluginData` entry for the GAV coordinates for `lib-alpha`.

Here's a sketch of what I want to see:

```kotlin
// aggregating-project/build.gradle.kts

plugins {
  id("my-plugin")
}

dependencies {
  myPlugin(project(":lib-alpha"))
  myPlugin(project(":lib-beta"))
}

data class AggregatedPluginData(
  val sourceCoords: String,
  val resources: ConfigurableFileCollection,
  val classpath: ConfigurableFileCollection,
)

fun aggregatePluginData(
  resourcesResolver: Configuration,
  classpathResolver: Configuration,
) {
  
  // first step, do something like this?
  val resources = mapOf(
    "org.example:lib-alpha:1.2.3" to files("lib-alpha/resources/1.txt"),
    "org.example:lib-beta:1.2.3" to files("lib-beta/resources/x.png"),
  )
  val classpaths = mapOf(
    "org.example:lib-alpha:1.2.3" to files("/path/to/dependency1.jar"),
    "org.example:lib-beta:1.2.3" to files("/path/to/dependency2.jar"),
  )
  
  // combine the lists...
}

val combinedResourcesTask by tasks.registering {
  
  val aggregatedData = aggregatePluginData()
  
  //...
}
```

I'm using Gradle 8.6. The plugin must be compatible with Build Cache and Configuration cache.